# Trouble mocking ES6 Module using jest.unstable_mockModule

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm attempting to mock a call to a class instance function on an ES6 module being imported by the code under test. I've followed the progress of the ES6 support and eventually stumbled onto this PR https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/10976 which mentioned that in 27.1.1 support for jest.unstable_mockModule was added. I upgraded my version of Jest to take advantage and while the test doesn't error, it also doesn't seem to actually mock the module either.

This is the module under test:

```js
// src/Main.mjs

import Responder from './Responder.mjs'
import Notifier from './Notifier.mjs'

export default {
  async fetch(request, environment, context) {
    let response

    try {
      response = new Responder(request, environment, context).respond()
    } catch (error) {
      return new Notifier().notify(error)
    }

    return response
  }
}
```

Here is the test:

```js
// test/Main.test.mjs

import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import main from '../src/Main.mjs'

describe('fetch', () => {
  test('Notifies on error', async () => {
    const mockNotify = jest.fn();
    
    jest.unstable_mockModule('../src/Notifier.mjs', () => ({
      notify: mockNotify
    }))

    const notifierMock = await import('../src/Notifier.mjs');
    
    await main.fetch(null, null, null)

    expect(mockNotify).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

I'm trying to mock the call to Notify to expect it to have been called and while this will run, it raises an exception from inside the `Notifier.notify()` that is supposed to be mocked, so it appears that it isn't being mocked at all.

What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `main.fetch` is returning? Is `respond` throwing an exception as you expect?

Comment: Yes, `respond` does raise the exception as I expect and the call to notifier is made which in turn raises an exception which is the part I would not expect had `notify()` been mocked properly.

Comment: @rmontgomery429, did you get this work, or figure out a workable pattern?

Answer (score 14):

I believe it's because you're importing main at the start of the file. You need to do a dynamic import the same way as Notifier.mjs

```
// test/Main.test.mjs

import { jest } from '@jest/globals'


describe('fetch', () => {
  test('Notifies on error', async () => {
    const mockNotify = jest.fn();
    
    jest.unstable_mockModule('../src/Notifier.mjs', () => ({
      notify: mockNotify
    }))

    const notifierMock = await import('../src/Notifier.mjs');
    const main = await import('../src/Main.mjs');
    
    await main.fetch(null, null, null)

    expect(mockNotify).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```