# unstable_mockModule not mocking ESM

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules, ts-jest

I'm using ESM in my project. All of my `.ts` files are transpiled into `.js` stored in the 'dist' folder. An example layout of my directory structure is:

```bash
dist/
├─ src/
│  ├─ store/
│  │  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ strategies/
│  │  ├─ scalping/
│  │  │  ├─ main.js 
src/
├─ store/
│  │  ├─ index.ts
├─ strategies/
│  │  ├─ scalping/
│  │  │  ├─ main.ts 
test/
├─ strategies/
│  │  ├─ scalping/
│  │  │  ├─ main.test.ts
```

The `moduleResolution` in my tsconfig.json is "NodeNext"

My `jest.config.ts` is:

```js
import type { Config } from "jest"

const config: Config = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    displayName: "scalper",
    testTimeout: 60000, // 30 secs - Necessary for when testing timers
    globalSetup: "<rootDir>/test/jest/setup.ts",
    globalTeardown: "<rootDir>/test/jest/teardown.ts",
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [ "/node_modules/" ],
    testMatch: ["<rootDir>/test/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/test/.*/__mocks__", "<rootDir>/dist/"],
    testEnvironment: "node",
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^(.*)\\.js$": "$1",
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                useESM: true
            }
        ]
    },
}

export default config
```

My `test/main/index.test.ts` is:

```js
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import * as fs from "fs"
import * as path from "path"
import appRoot from "app-root-path"

const params = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(appRoot.path, 'test/strategies/scalping/main/params.json'), 'utf8'))

import * as strategies from "../../../../src/strategies/scalping/index.js"

describe('main', () => {
    it('Should create a valid scalp trade', async () => {
        const { builtMarket, config } = params

        // Mocking of ESM requires dynamic imports
        // https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm
        jest.unstable_mockModule('../../../../src/store/index.js', () => ({
            getScalpRunners: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(params as never)
        }))

        const store = await import('../../../../src/store/index.js')

        await strategies.scalping(builtMarket, config)
    })
})
```

The method `getScalpRunners` I would have expected to be mocked but it is not & calls the main definition. I have looked at following the documentation of mocking ESM modules *(linked in the code)* & I have looked a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393176/trouble-mocking-es6-module-using-jest-unstable-mockmodule) but it's still not working.

A snippet of my `src/strategies/scalping/main.ts` is:

```js
import store from "../../store/index.js"

export default async function(builtMarket: BuiltMarket, config: Config): Promise<BuiltMarket | undefined> {
    try {
        const validMarket = isValidMarket(builtMarket, config)

        if (validMarket) {
            const polledRunners: ScalpRunner[] | undefined = await store.getScalpRunners({
                eventId: builtMarket._eventId,
                marketId: builtMarket._marketId
            })

            // other stuff...
        }
    } catch(err: any) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

Why is this not being mocked correctly?

If I output the value of `store` in `index.test.ts` then it is the mocked version of the module. However, in `main.ts` it is the un-mocked version of the module.

Comment: I would drop ts-jest and jest in favor of tsx and nodes native test runner.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue but it looks very messy. I altered the import of `../../../../src/strategies/scalping/index.js` to a dynamic import instead of a static one to ensure it was using the mocked one & had to mock a default export for `store/index.js`.

`index.test.ts`:

```js
// Not usually required to import global but apparently the use of ESM does need it
// https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#differences-between-esm-and-commonjs
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

// Mocking of ESM requires dynamic imports
// https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm
jest.unstable_mockModule('../../../../src/store/index.js', () => ({
    default: {
        getScalpRunners: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(params as never)
    }
}))

import * as fs from "fs"
import * as path from "path"
import appRoot from "app-root-path"

const params = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(appRoot.path, 'test/strategies/scalping/main/params.json'), 'utf8'))

// Mocking of ESM requires dynamic imports
// This ensures that the import is done AFTER the mock
const store = await import('../../../../src/store/index.js')
const strategies = await import('../../../../src/strategies/scalping/index.js')

describe('main', () => {
    it('Should create a valid scalp trade', async () => {
        const { builtMarket, config } = params

        await strategies.scalping(builtMarket, config)
    })
})
```

Comment: This could be similar to my issue, I have to mock a simple api call with axios and async/await, but since I am totally new of jest and I'm using ES6 modules, I think i need to write the `jest.unstable_mockModule` factory. Any idea on how to do it, assuming the function is `myFunc()` and I use at the top `import {myFunc()} from ../utils/backendCalls.js` ?